# AJAX and js.history. How to get previous working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js

I have a page made with AJAX, but as you all know, by default it won't support history. I am now trying to use history.js in order to make the history work. Currently, when the user clicks a picture at the index.php, ajax loads stuff from the folders.php. At the same time, I am saving the url and the idd(which changes depending on what picture user clicked) to history:

```
    window.history.pushState(null,null,"folders.php?idd="+$idd);
```

Lets say the id of the clicked picture is 3, so the code is

```
    window.history.pushState(null,null,"folders.php?idd=3");
```

The data loaded is more pictures, and the user can now select one of them again, and the index.php loads image gallery from the page images.php. Now if the user wants to go back(to see data loaded from folders.php), and he uses "previous" button, nothing happens.

Of course, if I just change page to folders.php?idd=3, it won't work, as all the layouts are in the index.php. Other pages just contains data.

So what do I need to add there to make it work? Or is that just impossible?

Comment: Funny. I used couple of hours googling this, and I didn't even came across with pjax. Thx for the tip, I'll check that out asap.

Comment: There isn't much good documentations/examples for the pjax, I think I keep it as back up solution. So if there is a ways to get history.js working, that would be nice.